# Speed up numpy nested loop

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, slice

I am writing a simulation for a wireless network in python using numpy and cython, where suppose there is a number of nodes `no_nodes` scattered randomly on the 2d plane which send out some waveforms and their respective receivers, again scattered randomly on the 2d plane. Each transmitting node produces a waveform I call `output` (each one can produce an output of different length).

What I want to do is to sum these outputs from each node to one big waveform that will be the input to each receiver for demodulation etc. Now two key-points:

- the transmitters send asynchronously and therefore a `start_clock` and an `end_clock` has to be maintened per transmitting node so as to sum the waveforms properly
- the output of the `j` transmitting node will be attenuated before being received by the `i` node according to a function `attenuate(i,j)`

So here is the code:

```
#create empty 2d array (no_rx_nodes x no_samples for each waveform)
waveforms = np.zeros((no_nodes, max(end_clock))) 

for i in range(no_nodes): #calculate the waveform for each receiver
    for j in range(no_nodes): #sum the waveforms produced by each transmitter
        waveforms[i, start_clock[j]:end_clock[j]] += output[j,:] * attenuate(i,j)
return waveforms
```

Some comments on the above:

- `output[j, :]` is the output waveform of transmitter j
- `waveforms[i,:]` is the waveform received by receiver i

I hope it is fairly clear what I am trying to accomplish here. Because the waveforms produced are very large (about 10^6 samples), I also tried turning this code into cython but without noticing any particular speedup (maybe 5-10x better but no more). I was wondering if there is anything else I can resort to so as to get a speed up because it is a real bottleneck to the whole simulation (it takes to compute almost as much time as the rest of the code, which in fact is quite more complicated than that).

Comment: The code seems fairly efficient as it is - unless `no_nodes` is large. Are you sure the bottleneck isn't in `attenuate`?

Comment: no_nodes is about 10-20 at most. attenuate is just a simple multiplication drawn from a distance matrix

Comment: the problem i guess is the huge number of samples as I mention in the main text

Comment: If `no_nodes` is 20, the double for will execute 400 times, so I don't think that will be a problem. The addition also seems pretty efficient to me, but I'm by no means a expert on numpy. You may find that there's no real bottleneck here, and that it's simply unfeasible to multiply such a large number of samples. Can you downsample the signal in any way? Or perform attenuation previously?

Comment: for your reference, I just timed how much it takes to execute the command in the nested loop and in average it takes 4.13ms.. so 4.13*20*20 = 1652ms = 1.65sec which is way too much if you want to run a monte carlo simulation with that. without the `attenuate` multiplication it takes 2ms, however, I am afraid I cannot avoid it. Downsampling again is not an option as I have already downsampled as I could (after that the Niquist rate won't be met and the waveforms will be useless)

Comment: Setting your problem up for multithreading is relatively straightforward, but the speed-up will be smaller than the number of CPUs in your system, so it is unlikely to be better than that 5-10x that you deem insufficient.

Comment: Actually I have tried that, considering it is an "embarrassingly parallel" problem. I used joblib but it was 10x slower; maybe I just didn't configure it properly (I used the shared memory option), I don't know..

Comment: The only way I can see of properly vectorising this loop is to precompute the attenuate matrix. If you could do that I'm sure you could rewrite your problem as a tensor inner product and do it in a single operation.

Comment: @HenryGomersall, any suggestions how to precompute the attenuate matrix? All attenuate does is grab a value from a 2D distance matrix multiplied by a constant. Nothing special there.

Comment: Can you post the code for attenuate?

Comment: @HenryGomersall `(attn_const/distances[i,j] ** attn_expon`, where `attn_const`, `attn_expon` are constants and `distances[i,j]` gives the distance between the i and the j node (i being the receiverm j the transmitter in the for loop)

Comment: @user113478 so you can just compute the matrix `attenuate = (attn_const/distances) ** attn_expon`, which will yield an array the same size as distances, right?

Comment: @Ophion, you can try it by populating a 2D (20 x 10^6) output matrix using `np.random.rand` and a 2D `distance` (20x20) matrix by using again `np.random.rand * 10` if you want

Comment: @HenryGomersall, yes that is correct!

Comment: Can you make `end_clock[j] - start_clock[j]` constant for all `j`? This means you can compute the waveforms in a single operation and then simply populate `waveforms`. Better still, change you algorithm so you use a waveforms array in which you compute a full row rather than some subset of the row.

Comment: I can't fix `end_clock[j] - start_clock[j]` but I would be able to produce column aligned outputs for example `aligned_output` with total length max(end_clock) (as in the waveform) if I could somehow pad with zeros before start_clock and after end_clock.. Of course that can be done with a for loop but if there is something more efficient it would be nice

Comment: I have forgotten to mention that `output` array is the result of convolution so it cannot be manipulated otherwise

Comment: oh, post that (in the original question) too. I mean, show as much code as you can. Your operation is linear so you could always reorder if that makes sense from an algorithmic perspective. Is your code to compute at a point the sum of all the Green functions? If so, where did you get the algorithm from? In the linear case (which it seems you have) my understanding is this is best solved in the Fourier domain.

Comment: Well output is the result of the convolution of an array representing a pulse in the time domain and an array used as a mask for where this pulse is going to be placed in time (and hence convolution)

Comment: @user113478 right, well it's fairly typical to perform convolutions in the Fourier domain. The problem is, you're asking for help on some small aspect of your algorithm, when I suspect the best strategy is to redesign the whole algorithm. My advice is go away and think hard about the algorithm.

Comment: ok, I will probably try that, thank you so much for your time and feedback!! I am honestly grateful

Answer (score 5):

this is a memory bandwidth bound problem with about 3GB/s memory bandwidth the best you can get out of this is around 2-4ms for the inner loop.
to reach that bound you need to block your inner loop to utilize the cpu caches better (numexpr does this for you):

```
for i in range(no_nodes):
    for j in range(no_nodes):
        # should be chosen so all operands fit in the (next-to-)last level cache
        # first level is normally too small to be usable due to python overhead
        s  = 15000 
        a = attenuation[i,j]
        o = output[j]
        w = waveforms[i]
        for k in range(0, w.size, s): 
            u = min(k + s, w.size)
            w[k:u] += o[k:u] * a
        # or: numexpr.evaluate("w + o * a", out=w)
```

using float32 data instead of float64 should also half the memory bandwidth requirements and double the performance.

To get larger speedups you have to redesign your full algorithm to have a better data locality

Comment: Great workaround, thank you so much! Could you let me know how the numexpr version would be more or less? Because I have it installed but haven't tried it very much yet!

Comment: should be just numexpr.evaluate("w + o * a", out=w) instead of the loop

Comment: Do you know whether numexpr expressions can be run in cython?

Comment: you can call any python function from cython, that includes numexpr. But if you already cythonize the inner loop you don't need numexpr anymore (unless you profit from numexpr's parallelization or VML support)

Answer (score 4):

I think it is memory access that's crippling your performance, and there is probably little you can do there. You can speed-up things a little bit by using in-place operations and preallocating and reusing buffers. As a toy example for your code, without the time alignment:

```
def no_buffer(output, attenuate):
    waveforms = np.zeros_like(output)
    for i in xrange(len(output)):
        for j in xrange(len(output)):
            waveforms[i,:] += output[j, :] * attenuate[i, j]

    return waveforms

def with_buffer(output, attenuate):
    waveforms = np.zeros_like(output)
    buffer_arr = np.empty_like(output[0])
    for i in xrange(len(output)):
        for j in xrange(len(output)):
            np.multiply(output[j, :], attenuate[i, j], out=buffer_arr)
            np.add(waveforms[i, :], buffer_arr, out=waveforms[i, :])

    return waveforms

o = np.random.rand(20, 1e6)
a = np.random.rand(20, 20)

In [17]: np.allclose(no_buffer(o, a), with_buffer(o, a))
Out[17]: True

In [18]: %timeit no_buffer(o, a)
1 loops, best of 3: 2.3 s per loop

In [19]: %timeit with_buffer(o, a)
1 loops, best of 3: 1.57 s per loop
```

Which I guess is better than nothing.

Of course, if you can get rid of the time alignment thing, your operation is simply a matrix multiplication, and it is best to let BLAS deal with that. On my system, using MKL:

```
In [21]: np.allclose(with_buffer(o, a), np.dot(o.T, a.T).T)
Out[21]: True

In [22]: %timeit np.dot(o.T, a.T).T
10 loops, best of 3: 123 ms per loop
```

Comment: If it's really about size of the arrays and you can't use `dot`, it might be worthwhile looking into `numexpr`.

Comment: @Midnighter You are likely better off writing a few simple loops where you complete your dot product in chunks.

Comment: @Jaime, I thought I knew linear algebra, well I have changed my mind after that!! Great answer, thank you so much!

Comment: @Jaime, what if I need to convolve `output[j,:]` with `attenuate[i,j,:]`, where `attenuate` would be a 3d array (no_nodes x no_nodes x no_samples_for_channel_model) (suppose that attenuate is a channel model representing the channel that the signal from transmitter `j` goes through to reach receiver `i`. Could you propose a workaround for that as well? Could that somehow be manipulated using np.dot ?

Answer (score 2):

Just for the sake of experimentation suppose that output from each transmitter is time aligned, and therefore no clocks are required. I came up with a version using heavily broadcasting and thus eliminating the for loops completely. However, it is 3x slower. 
Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import time

def calc(no_nodes):

    output = np.random.rand(no_nodes, 7e5) #some random data, 7e5 samples here
    attenuate= np.random.rand(no_nodes,no_nodes) #some random data
    start_time = time.time()
    output_per_node = np.zeros((no_nodes,no_nodes,7e5))
    output_per_node += output[None, :, :]
    data = attenuate[:,:,None] * output_per_node
    waveforms = np.sum(data, axis=1)
    end_time = time.time()
    print end_time - start_time
    return waveforms
```

The regular nested for-loop implementation would be:

```
def calc1(no_nodes):
    output = np.random.rand(no_nodes, 7e5)
    attenuation = np.random.rand(no_nodes,no_nodes)
    waveforms = np.zeros((no_nodes, 7e5))
    start_time = time.time()
    for i in range(no_nodes):
        for j in range(no_nodes):
            waveforms[i] += output[j] * attenuation[i,j]
    print time.time() - start_time
    return waveforms
```

So what is really going on here? Numpy is supposed to be so blazingly fast you can't keep up with. I don't say it generally isn't, but in this particular example something is not going on well. Even if you convert both these codes to cython, the second one (with for loops) is much faster than the one with broadcasting. What do you believe I am doing wrong here?
Note: try with no_nodes=10

For anyone interested you can find the ipython notebook with the above code displaying the difference in performance, both in ipynb and html form here:

- [IPython notebook in html](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37017703/Numpy/Should%20you%20remove%20nested%20loops%20or%20not_.html) (no edits possible)
- [IPython notebook in .ipynb](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37017703/Numpy/Should%20you%20remove%20nested%20loops%20or%20not_.ipynb) (for your use)

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I liked your approach, did you check the equality with `np.allclose()`, for example, to see if one method is giving the same result as the other. You should post this very last question as a new answer, it will create a good discussion...

Comment: @SaulloCastro, yes they return exactly the same, in fact I will post an ipython notebook for anyone interested in a couple of minutes

Comment: In your solution using broadcasting you are creating an array 20 times larger than any array used in the other solution. I think that's where the slow down is coming from. If you can really do without the time alignment, look carefully into your code: you have reimplemented matrix multiplication, and `np.dot` can do that many times faster than you...

Comment: @Jaime, could you elaborate on that? How would that be done using np.dot?