# Avoid Numpy Index For loop

Tags: performance, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ufunc

Is there any way to avoid using a second `for` loop for an operation like this?

```
for x in range(Size_1):
    for y in range(Size_2):
        k[x,y] = np.sqrt(x+y) - y
```

Or is there a better way to optimize this? Right now it is incredibly slow for large sizes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Speed up numpy nested loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23565573/speed-up-numpy-nested-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution with [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
X,Y = np.ogrid[:Size_1,:Size_2]
k_out = np.sqrt(X+Y) - Y
```

Answer (score 0):

Supplementing Divakar's solution: If `Y` and `X` are not new ranges but some preexisting vectors of numbers, use `np.ix_`:

```
Y, X = np.array([[1.3, 3.5, 2], [2.0, -1, 1]])
Y, X = np.ix_(Y, X) # does the same as Y = Y[:, None]; X = X[None, :]
out = np.sqrt(Y+X) - X
```